# PDFBox : Extraction of data from table

Tags: java, pdfbox, extract

How to extract data from a table in a pdf using pdfbox?

In this process, Index of Text and contents can be found using PDContentStream and PageStripper classes.Index of lines in the table have to be found, Can anyone help with which class to extend and which method to implement?

I have tried the following for extracting the start index of texts:

```
public class Tables {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        BufferedWriter wr;
        File input = new File("test.pdf");
        File output = new File("SampleText.txt"); 
        PDDocument pd=new PDDocument();
        pd=PDDocument.load(input);

        //      PDFTextStripper pds=new PDFTextStripper();
        //      String text=pds.getText(pd);
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper()
        {
            @Override
            protected void startPage(PDPage page) throws IOException
            {
                startOfLine = true;
                super.startPage(page);
            }

            @Override
            protected void writeLineSeparator() throws IOException
            {
                startOfLine = true;
                super.writeLineSeparator();
            }

            @Override
            protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
            {
                if (startOfLine)
                {
                    TextPosition firstProsition = textPositions.get(0);
                    writeString(String.format("[%s]", firstProsition.getYDirAdj()));
                    startOfLine = false;
                }
                super.writeString(text, textPositions);
            }
            boolean startOfLine = true;
        };
        wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
        stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.close();
        }
        // I use close() to flush the stream.
        wr.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I did a similar project where I had to extract data from tables.

You have two options here:-

1) You can use tabula (It is an open source tool for extracting tables from pdf). http://tabula.technology/ 
https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula
You can use tabula command line tool in your code and extract the data from a specific region.

2) You need to devise your own algorithm for extracting the tabular data.
    If you are going to go for the second option then you would need to extract coordinates of the text also. You can override writestring method of pdfTextStripper class (you can google about this). Then you need to think on how to use those information to get the details you need. (Co-ordinates can be very helpful).

If you have the pdf in a standard format then I suggest you to use tabula as there is not much to be do.

Comment: Going to your 2nd option, I have already found the co-ordinates of text as shown in the code I've attached.Extracting the co-ordinates of line in a table is what I require.

Comment: If you mean graphic line (and not line of text), then i think you would have to do so by converting the pdf into image and then travesring the image pixels by pixels . 
There is a method in tabula which returns the coordinates of each line segment found in a given image.

Comment: Does your project have a pdfs of same format. If you can upload a sample file then I would have a better idea.

Comment: For (2), see the ExtractTextByArea.java example.

Comment: Can you please explain which methods I should be overriding to find the index of a line using ExtractTextByArea. @TilmanHausherr

Comment: I assume that with "index", you mean the coordinates. One possibility would be to render the image at 72dpi with the PDFToImage tool. Then use a graphics tool (e.g. IrfanView), create a rectangle, and write down the coordinates. Then recalculate the y values, as y = 0 is the bottom. Thus y2 = height - y.